# Is a table view with custom cells still a plain table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[Apple defines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) a plain table view like the following:

> Plain. In the plain style, rows can be separated into labeled sections
>   and an optional index can appear vertically along the right edge of
>   the view. A header can appear before the first item in a section, and
>   a footer can appear after the last item.

Or in [more detail](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html):

> A table view in the plain (or regular) style displays rows that
>   stretch across the screen and have a creamy white background (see
>   Figure 1-1). A plain table view can have one or more sections,
>   sections can have one or more rows, and each section can have its own
>   header or footer title. (A header or footer may also have a custom
>   view, for instance one containing an image). When the user scrolls
>   through a section with many rows, the header of the section floats to
>   the top of the table view and the footer of the section floats to the
>   bottom.
>
> A variation of plain table views associates an index with sections for
>   quick navigation; Figure 1-2 shows an example of this kind of table
>   view, which is called an indexed list. The index runs down the right
>   edge of the table view. Entries in the index correspond to section
>   header titles. Touching an item in the index scrolls the table view to
>   the associated section. For example, the section headings could be
>   two-letter state abbreviations, and the rows for a section could be
>   the cities in that state; touching at a certain spot in the index
>   displays the cities for the selected state. The rows in indexed lists
>   should not have disclosure indicators or detail disclosure buttons,
>   because these interfere with the index.

Now you can have custom cells instead of the four default styles (Default, Subtitle, Value 1, Value 2). If you have a "crazy" custom cell is it still a "plain" table view? Or is it only valid for the default styles? Because the docs only shows the default styles on the screenshots.

Comment: btw: what happened when you tried?

Comment: It does work but it doesn't mean if it is allowed by Apple. I wanted to use the indexer with my custom cells and I haven't seen this before (only with the default styles of the cell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableview style affects the table view — not the table view cells. So yes, a plain tableview can — and  should have — custom cells.